# How do i update an emulator on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to know how I can in Android Studio update the framework.
Once I change the content of a file how can I update the emulator to the new modified version?

Answer (score 0):

If you started the emulator you can relaunch your App inside Android Studio to update the content on the emulator. If you want to speed up the process just click `Apply Changes` next to `Run`. That only makes android studio relaunch the App with the updated files.

If you instead want to update the android OS version of your emulator, you can do that by opening the `Device Manager` under `Tools>Device Manager` and download a new android OS. If you then create a new device you have an updated emulator.

Comment: Thanks, but in case I want to update the content of an operating system file to have a customized version of Android what should I do?

Comment: Would have to go through a tutorial on creating a custom android os branch like here: https://www.androidauthority.com/build-custom-android-rom-720453/